# How to inject "history" into a subversion repository?

Tags: svn, history, starteam

We're migrating from StarTeam (aka "the horrible") to SubVersion (aka "the alleged great"). We've already migrated the files by doing a "dumb" commit to all files and started working on the SubVersion repository.

However, we're still forced to use StarTeam because we lack the per-file history of check-ins. Is it possible to inject that history into SubVersion after the first check-in has been done? If yes - how?

Comment: I'm curious if you ended up getting the full history into svn. I'm hoping to do the same migration at my workplace, and I'd like to learn how your transition went.

Comment: no, and it stinks. We have to work with the old source control (StarTeam) whenever we need to check why or when was something done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

To get the history into subversion you have to start from scratch and incorporate every revision from StarTeam into subversion.

Here's a starting point for doing that: [Importer for SVN](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer.php)